# Save textbox data and return from localstorage - angularJS -

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, return, local-storage

When page refresh I want to return data from scope to textbox value. How can I do it with only update button?

Example: [Plunker](https://goo.gl/VpB2ie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this changes in your plunker index.html

```
<script>


angular.module("example", ["ngStorage"])
.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $localStorage) {

$scope.save = function() {
$localStorage.message = $scope.zafer;
console.log(zafer);
}

$scope.load = function() {
$scope.zafer = $localStorage.message;

} 

})

</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="example">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController" ng-init="load()">

<input type="text" ng-model="zafer">

<button ng-click="save()">Update</button>



</div>
</body>
```

Comment: friend, doesn't work on ios. android is working. when page refresh, return data. but ios not working. Do you know why ?